# При запуске автотеста, Хром запускает и сразу же вылетает

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\MSi1000\\Desktop\\QA по работе\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так разумеется он будет сразу вылетать, так как код выполнился и браузер автоматически закрылся.

Попробуйте после `driver.get("https://google.com")` написать `time.sleep(5)`